# Help Hokuyo Laser

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody!  I need  help to configure Hokuyo laser.  For my university project  I mount an Hokuyo Laser on a mobile robot and I need an obstacle avoidance algorythm  with ROS. I have already odometry's data available. Where can I found info about any obstacle avoidance code? I am at first experience with Ros and I have already seen in the Documentation, but  I am very confused!!
Help me, please!
Best regards everybody!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99801/help-hokuyo-laser/) by [gennaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/8666/gennaro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are going to want to check out move_base (http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) and the rest of the navigation stack (http://wiki.ros.org/navigation?distro=hydro).

---

Originally posted by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) with karma: 377 on 2013-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0